# Set opacity of image in pygame

Tags: python, image, pygame, surface

Okay guys, I'm trying to fade out an image. So given this:

```
img_ = pygame.image.load('circle.png')
screen.blit(img_, [100, 100])
```

how can I change the opacity of `img_`? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Pygame surfaces have a method named `set_alpha()` for this, which takes a value between 0 and 255.

Relevant docs: https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.set_alpha